# React - call a child components method from Parents ComponentDidmount()

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent component

```
    class Parent extends React {
        componentDidMount() {
            document.getElementById(this.props.grandParentElemntId).addEventListener("mouseleave",this.handleClick);
         }
        handleClick() {
            this.childcomponent2.method();
        }
         render() {
             return(
               <div>
                  <ChildComponent1 />
                      <div>
                          <ChildComponent2 ref = {(ref) => this.childcomponent2 = ref} />
                      </div>
               </div>
             );
         }
 }
```

I am trying to call child component 2's method on a mouseleave event triggered right after the parent component is mounted. However I keep getting an error as the method is not accessible. I have been looking at react documentation for refs, but didn't get a solution for this issue. Does anybody have a solution for this?

Comment: `extends React.Component`, not `React`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using state and props to handle this instead of trying to force vanilla js eventlisteners:

[**Working JSFiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/gkysmsqz/8/)

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    mouseLeft: false
  };

  componentDidMount() {

this.parent.addEventListener("mouseleave",this.handleMouseEvt.bind(this, true));

this.parent.addEventListener("mouseenter",this.handleMouseEvt.bind(this, false));
  }

  handleMouseEvt = mouseLeft => {
    this.setState({ mouseLeft });
  };

  render() {
    return(
      <div ref={ ref => this.parent = ref } className="parent">
        <p>Trigger mouseLeave on me!</p>
        <ChildComponent1 />
        <div>
          <ChildComponent2 mouseLeft={this.state.mouseLeft} ref = {(ref) => this.childcomponent2 = ref} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
 }

 class ChildComponent2 extends React.Component {
        someMethod = () => {
        alert('Did someMethod() in ChildComponent2');
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if(nextProps !== this.props && nextProps.mouseLeft) {
        this.someMethod();
      }
    }

        render() {
        return <div>Child 2</div>
    }
 }
```